# spring-boot's gradle plugin bootRepackage task gives deprecation warning

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Following is my gradle bulld -

```
allprojects {
    group = "org.coderearth"
    version = "0.1.SNAPSHOT"

    ext {
        springBootVersion = "1.4.3.RELEASE"
    }
}


project(":core") {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.21'
        compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.7'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}


project.ext {
    recipeModules = subprojects.findAll {
        it.name.startsWith('recipe') || it.name == "service"
    }
}


configure(project.ext.recipeModules) {
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
    }
}


subprojects {
    task info {
        doLast {
            println "========================================================="
            println "\t project.group = $project.group"
            println "\t project.name = $project.name"
            println "\t project.parent = $project.parent.name"
            println "\t project.version = $project.version"
            println "========================================================="
        }
    }
}
```

service/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
}

// bootRepackage.enabled = false
```

I am seeing one build warning while running `build` task.

```
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:service:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:service:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:service:classes UP-TO-DATE
:service:findMainClass
:service:jar UP-TO-DATE
:service:bootRepackage
The ProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
ModuleDependency.getConfiguration() has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Use ModuleDependency.getTargetConfiguration() instead.
:service:assemble
:service:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:service:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:service:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:service:test UP-TO-DATE
:service:check UP-TO-DATE
:service:build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.973 secs
```

The strange thing is - if I disable bootRepackage in service/build.gradle it just go away. though its just a warning but I am curious to know what am I missing. I believe there is something that springboot's gradle plugin uses is deprecated but if it's in my build - then I need to fix it.

Thanks in advance,
/kp

Comment: gradle 3.3? looks like: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7734

Comment: yes. gradle 3.3

Comment: it is a problem in Spring Boot then, it is fixed in the upcoming version `1.5` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/dac249fb0d721fc9f17dafd1abbd17508f12f7ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently found that its spring-boot's issue which is fixed in upcoming version 1.5 (currently its 1.4.3.RELEASE).

Waiting for this release to come and check compatibility with our projects.

Thanks to @Thanksforallthefish